# To find the basis of quotient space $\frac{C}{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $C$ & $R$ are vector spaces over $R$ then find the basis for quotient space $\frac{C}{R}$

I know the basis for $C$ over R is {$i$,1}.
What is basis for $R$ over $R$?

Also, what is the basis for quotient space $\frac{C}{R}$ ?

Comment: E.g. $\{1\}$...

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is infinite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$, but one-dimensional over $\Bbb R$. In other words, how restrictive you are with your coefficients greatly affects the dimension of the vector space.

Comment: There is no "the basis" in this case, but **a basis** .

Comment: @DonAntonio There is, however, "the _standard_ basis". But I agree.

Comment: @DonAntonio By "in this case" you mean in all cases but $V=0$ and $V=\mathbb F_2$, since these are the only vector spaces with unique bases :)

Comment: @MooS ...Yes indeed.

Comment: @Arthur "Standard" may heavily depend both on the particular vector space *and* on the person...

Comment: @DonAntonio Is the answer is {i+R}?I am finding all possible questions related to quotient space.I found this.Is my answer correct?

Comment: @Believer, if we're talking of $\;\Bbb R\,,\,\,\Bbb C\;$ ,as it seems was the intention here, then $\;\dim\Bbb C_{\Bbb R}=2\;$ , so any basis has to have **two elements** . Can you think of such an easy basis? It is just a matter of remembering the (perhaps most usual) definition of the complex numbers.

Comment: @DonAntonio My explanation:for given case,basis of C is {i,1} and basis of R is {1} ,So basis of C/R is {i + R} .Is it fine?

Comment: @BEliever, again: when you say "basis of $\;\Bbb C\;$...",  you **must** state with respect to what field. For example , $\;\{1\}\;$ is a basis for $\;\Bbb C\;$ over itself...And pay attention: $\;i+\Bbb R\;$ is **not** a vector (number) in $\;\Bbb C\;$ ...in fact, it is not even something we can be sure of.

Comment: @DonAntonio In my previous comment I am taking field as R for both C and R.What is the correct answer then for basis of C/R?

Comment: I told you: it must have **two linearly independent** (over $\;\Bbb R$) vectors (elements in $\;\Bbb C$), so $\;\{1,\,i\}\;$ fulifll this...can you prove it?